# Check every row of a df column for values in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

The column I'm interested in the dataframe looks like

```py
names=['nonsoluable water', 'water percentage 98% grade', 'special chemical with grade chlorine', 'name with value']
```

There are other columns too. Those are just numbers/identifiers.

I need every row of the column to be checked if it has any value from the list:

```py
check_for_these = waters, grades, %, chemical
```

If the column has any of those values from the list, I want it to flag the row in a new column.

I've tried this:

```py
df['names'].apply(lambda x: any([k in x for k in check_for_these]))
```

but it raises errors/gives wrong output.

And the `isin` function also raises errors:

```py
df['match'] = df["names"].isin(check_for_these)
print(df)
```

I want the output to be like the image given below

[image]

Comment: I've searched stackoverflow for this question already and havent been able to find an answer so ive asked it....why do people downvote? im a beginner....

Comment: People downvote for many reasons. Some good, some bad; but new users are often given a pass on things like formatting and community expectations. Everybody is here to make a good community and help. Votes are meant to indicate if a questions shows effort and is clear. I this case, what are the errors you're receiving. You can edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I couldn't understand what exactly you wanted to do. How did you like to flag the row? I think you are getting downvoted because of the lack of sufficient information. Try editing your question and giving us more information to help you solve your quetstion efficinetly.

Comment: For starters, I highly recommend not calling lists `list`. Aliasing over a language builtins can cause confusion.

Comment: Sharing a [mcve] helps also

Comment: ive edited it now - thank you guys

Comment: So if you have "water" in the column, you need it to be matched. But `check_for_these` doesn't have "water" but it has "waters"; can you clarify that?

Comment: Yeah i think im trying to do a fuzzy match to check the column for plurals/not plurals(s) as well- I want it to flag as long as it exists in the list even if the name has another letter after it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['flag'] = df['names'].str.contains('|'.join(check_for_these), regex=True, case=False).astype(int)
```

Comment: why? this won't match water

Comment: and matches "alchemically"

Comment: It just gave me true values for the entire list...

Comment: Hmm...can you share a sample of your dataframe with `print(df.head().to_dict())`? I used `df=pd.DataFrame({'names':['nonsoluable water', 'water percentage 98% grade', 'special chemical with grade chlorine', 'name with value']})` and  `check_for_these = ['waters', 'grades', '%', 'chemical']`, and ran my code, and it gave `0, 1, 1, 0`

Comment: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings\accessor.py:101: UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.
  return func(self, *args, **kwargs) - what can i do about this?

Comment: Will you please add your code to your question?

Comment: df1['check'] = df1['name_a_suffix'].str.contains('|'.join(my_list), regex=True, case=False).astype(int)

Comment: Do any items in `my_list` have parentheses in?

Comment: How would i use the escape function for regex here to skip (\, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $, ., #, )  ? like I dont want it to match on those characters

Comment: @richardec yes it does, some of them have ()

Comment: Let us [continue this disscussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241662/discussion-between-sid-and-richardec).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to be sure that all your data in names column is in correct format so you need to transform all letters in lower case, you can make it like this

```
df['name'] = df['name'].apply(lambda str : str.lower())
```

Now, you can use the operation 'in' for strings in python, this operation return true if a string is substring of another string; this operation is case sensitive that's why we care about lower case. This works like this

```
'hello' in 'all my friends, hello' ----> True
'$' in 'bitcoin is cheap $.$' ---------> True
'Hello' in 'hello world' --------------> False
```

so, in your case, you have the list

```
check_for_these = ['waters', 'grades', '%', 'chemical']
```

then you can make your 'true', 'false' valued pandas series with

```
df['names'].apply(lambda str: any([(reqWord in str) for reqWord in check_for_these]))
```

now you just have to do the map {True : 1, False : 0} and make the flag column, so the solution is

```
df['flag'] = df['names'].apply(lambda str: any([(reqWord in str) for reqWord in check_for_these])).map({True : 1, False : 0})
```

Note: You can omit the fist step by doing the next

```
df['flag'] = df['names'].apply(lambda str: any([(reqWord in str.lower()) for reqWord in check_for_these])).map({True : 1, False : 0})
```

Comment: While this may work, it's probably going to be somewhat slow as it's not vectorized. Using `apply` on a DataFrame or Series is generally considered an antipattern.

Comment: @richardec I would not say 'anti pattern', i may say 'it's not the best practice'. Or i am not seeing the pattern, what pattern do you suggest to fix this?.